# model.fit function using datasets stops training after 2 epochs

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-datasets, training-data, autoencoder

Trying to train a autoencoder model using tensorflow datasets. Trying to use model.fit function to train the model. The training is exiting after 2 epochs. Even after changing the epochs >2. It still stops after 2 epochs. Not using any earlystopping callback. Code snippet is as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#%% Create list file.

import glob
dir_path = 'TestImages/*.jpeg'
res = glob.glob(dir_path)
print(res)
images_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((res))

print(len(images_ds))
for file in images_ds:
    # print(type(file))
    print(file.numpy())


#%% Reading from directory using tf.data.Dataset.list_files 
def preprocess_image(file_path):
    String_file_path = bytes.decode(file_path.numpy())    
    
    image = io.imread(String_file_path)
    
    ImageDataTensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)  
    return (ImageDataTensor)

ImageData_ds = images_ds.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(preprocess_image, [x], [tf.float64]))
ImageData_ds = ImageData_ds.batch(1)

#%%
Img_Rows=768
Img_Cols = 192
from tensorflow.keras import layers,models

# Implmented using Max-pooling. 
#Encoder Model Design
encoder = models.Sequential()
encoder.add(layers.Conv2D(16, 3, strides = 1, padding ='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(Img_Rows,Img_Cols,1)))
encoder.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,strides=2))
encoder.add(layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides = 1, padding ='same', activation='relu'))
encoder.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,strides=2))
encoder.summary()

#Decoder Model Design
decoder = models.Sequential()
decoder.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(32,3,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
decoder.add(layers.UpSampling2D(2))
decoder.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(16,3,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
decoder.add(layers.UpSampling2D(2))
decoder.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1,3,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
decoder.add(layers.UpSampling2D(2))
decoder.summary()
#%%

from tensorflow.keras import losses,Model, optimizers
BatchSize = 1
Current_LR = 0.001
Current_Epochs = 10

# Create Model 
conv_autoencoder = Model(inputs=encoder.input,outputs=decoder(encoder.outputs))
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=Current_LR)
conv_autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss=losses.mean_squared_error)
#%%
#Train Model 

Current_history = conv_autoencoder.fit(tf.data.Dataset.zip( (ImageData_ds , ImageData_ds) ).as_numpy_iterator(), epochs=5)
```

Below screenshot shows its stopping after 2 epochs.I have tried changing different epochs, Initial epoch, epochs per step but not sure what is causing the stop. Also to be observed I get the same train loss for the two epochs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PDyr.png)

If i re-execute the same fit cell again i see the loss is decreasing but still the same train loss across the two epochs.

Tensorflow version =2.5, python version = 3.8.8